# biopython intellisense iin spyder

Tags: python-2.7, biopython, spyder

I'm using the anaconda spyder IDE for development in Biopython. I want the IDE to integrate intellisense and documentation for my code. For instance, when I define a biopython object such as:

```
*myseq = Seq("ACTGACTAT")*
```

and than when I do:

```
*myseq.*
```

I want the editor to suggest methods callable over this object and show it's documentation on the upper right corner of the IDE (under the object inspector). The same way it's done for Javadocs.

I'm using lubuntu 14 32-bit OS. It's working for my regular python scripts, but not for biopython objects. How can I integrate this into my IDE? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) Unfortunately, being unable to get completions of objects build through assignation is a limitation of the underlying libraries we use to do code completion.

We are investigating how we could improve this situation in the future. For reference, this is the issue where we are discussing this:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2162